# Xcrun PackageApplication, failed unable to copy application

Tags: xcode, command-line, build, terminal

I've created a simple application in Xcode. Setted up a provisioning for Debug and Release configuration.
I'm performing in terminal:

```
xcodebuild -target signtest -configuration Debug -sdk iphoneos clean build
```

And it is building correctly.
Now I'm trying to make an ipa file with this command:

```
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v /Users/admin/Desktop/signtest/signtest/build/Debug-iphoneos/signtest.app/  -o /Users/admin/Desktop/binaries/signtest.ipa
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Packaging application: '/Users/admin/Desktop/signtest/signtest/build/Debug-iphoneos/signtest.app/'
Arguments: verbose=1  output=/Users/admin/Desktop/binaries/signtest.ipa  
Environment variables:
HOME = /Users/admin
DISPLAY = /tmp/launch-vj2zx7/org.x:0
COMMAND_MODE = unix2003
VERSIONER_PERL_PREFER_32_BIT = no
SSH_AUTH_SOCK = /tmp/launch-YPyQMl/Listeners
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render = /tmp/launch-mcFbgX/Render
CODESIGN_ALLOCATE = /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
PWD = /Users/admin/Desktop/signtest/signtest
LANG = pl_PL.UTF-8
USER = admin
CLICOLOR = 1
LOGNAME = admin
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING = 0x1F6:29:42
SHLVL = 1
TERM_PROGRAM = Apple_Terminal
OLDPWD = /Users/admin/Desktop/signtest/signtest/signtest
_ = /usr/bin/xcrun
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION = 299
TERM_SESSION_ID = A74C6214-58A9-4CE6-9032-B902BD286253
PATH = /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
LSCOLORS = GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced
SHELL = /bin/bash
TMPDIR = /var/folders/k2/28y_cf8d4b387lr2kf6vlsjr0000gp/T/
TERM = xterm-256color
VERSIONER_PERL_VERSION = 5.12

Output directory: '/Users/admin/Desktop/binaries/signtest.ipa'
Temporary Directory: '/var/folders/k2/28y_cf8d4b387lr2kf6vlsjr0000gp/T/hbdHfiqg31'  (will NOT be deleted on exit when verbose set)
+ /bin/cp -Rp /Users/admin/Desktop/signtest/signtest/build/Debug-iphoneos/signtest.app/ /var/folders/k2/28y_cf8d4b387lr2kf6vlsjr0000gp/T/hbdHfiqg31/Payload
Program /bin/cp returned 0 : []
error: Unable to copy application '/Users/admin/Desktop/signtest/signtest/build/Debug-iphoneos/signtest.app/' into '/var/folders/k2/28y_cf8d4b387lr2kf6vlsjr0000gp/T/hbdHfiqg31/Payload'
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got this error  because of a trailing '/' on the app path:

This fails:

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v foobar.app/
```

This works:

```
xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v foobar.app
```

Comment: This is exactly what was causing my issue! You saved me a ton of trouble

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity, have you checked to make sure that you have proper permissions and that the source and destination directories exist? It looks like the copy command is failing. My guess is from a problem with the temp dir.

Comment: it is not a permission failure. cp returns 0 (no error). see the other response for the solution