# Xamarin Forms IPA generation on Jenkins

Tags: ios, jenkins, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm having some trouble to generate an IPA for my Xamarin Forms iOS project on Jenkins. I follow the documentation (http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/ci/jenkins_walkthrough/) and post a question on the xamarin forums for my problem, but it's really difficult to have an answer there so i'll try here.

I'm able to build the application with mdtool but there isn't any IPA file in my project after the end of Jenkins' job.

I see some discussion on the forum that tell to use the archive method instead of the build for mdtool. But that didn't change anything either.

I also try to use xcrun to create the IPA file after the application build, but i have that kind of error :

> error: Unable to copy application 'iOS/bin/iPhone/Release/Application.iOS.app/' into '/var/folders/v2/gnnclzrd2g98zqc89qn204km00007h/T/VXEBXe7WNV/Payload'

There's not a lot of explanation on how the IPA is generated on the documentation so i'd like to have a clarification on that.

Is anyone manage to create an IPA in Jenkins for their iOS Xamarin Forms project ? 
If so how do you do it ? I could give you more information about the Jenkins' job i use, ... if necessary.

Regards

Comment: What is the setup of your Jenkins instance i.e. where and on what is it installed. You will also need to post the build script you are using

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it was actually a xcrun error due to the use of a relative path for the output ipa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just find an answer after hours of search and it's kinda dumb.
xcrun give me an that error because my app path had a / in the end (like explained in that post [Xcrun PackageApplication, failed unable to copy application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536728/xcrun-packageapplication-failed-unable-to-copy-application)).

But then i had another error :

> error: Unable to create 'iOS/bin/iPhone/Release/volunteer.ipa'

The output option of xcrun need to be an absolute path not a relative one inside the project.
By using an absolute one, the IPA is generated :)